# I need help with my potential PhD Supervisor who showed interest

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, advisor

So I went to a University in Canada to speak with Graduate studies coordinator to learn more about the program. While visiting, I bumped into the Chair of the department who is one of the Supervisors that I would love to work with. When he realized I was there for a visit, he invited me to his office to discuss this further. I told him about my future plans and about me wanting to go into academia, and he suggested I skip Masters and roll into PhD instead (because I had 4 years of wet lab experience). He also mentioned that he is recruiting students for fall, and that he isnt guaranteeing anything now but does think I would be an excellent candidate. He asked about my GPA and when I told him he said it sounds good. Bottom line, he asked me to send him my CV and Transcript so he can check if I can fast track into PHD and insisted he would get back to me soon to advice me further. I emailed him on Thursday, (he checked my linkedin profile two hours after I emailed him). Today is Tuesday and he hasn't responded.

I know they can be very busy and I completely understand, but how should I follow up without sounding too annoying|? Should I do it through phone or email? And does him offering such on our initial non planned meeting sound promising? Would love to hear your feedbacks!

Comment: This may be my inner millennial talking, but why on Earth would you call someone for something like this??? Just send a nice email instead (or swing by their office, which is not applicable in this case) ;)

Comment: You do make sense!

Answer (score 2):

This is end of term, with classes to finish, assignments to return, exams to prepare, and if this person is the Chair all the non-sense that comes with the end of term: students complaining, special accommodation, *etc*.

If you have not heard in *one month*, start to worry.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you sent the CV as asked. He needs time to do some checking as you say. He is also busy with ordinary work. If you don't hear in a week, send him a note and ask what your next steps should be.

Academia can move pretty slowly and if he is involved in research as well as department head, then he is probably tied up. But after a week, a short note of interest should be fine.

Comment: Op showed interest by following up with the cv. A week? A month is more fitting given academia can be hectic...

Comment: @SolarMike, yes, except this was by invitation.